# Issue with Procedure in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, procedure

When I run my program for the first time, I would like to create the following procedure:

```
$returnCusProcedure = "
    DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllCustomers()
    BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS;
    END //
    DELIMITER ; ";

if(! $returnCusProcedure )
{
    die('Could not create procedure: ' . $conn->error);
}
else
{
    echo "Procedure created successfully<br/>";
}
```

It echos out that the procedure has completed successfully but when I call that procedure in MySQL, it returns that the procedure does not exist, am I missing something from above?

Comment: The above code isn't creating the procedure, only defining it as a string in PHP. And since the string is defined, the `if` condition will always evaluate to true (it will always echo success).

Comment: Ah I see, I'm only starting with PHP so I'm still getting familiar with it, ill try update it now, thanks for your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to actually execute those SQL statements. It would be something like:

```
$cusProcedure = "
    CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllCustomers()
    BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS;
    END"; // <-- No need to change delimiter, at least in this case

$returnCusProcedure = $conn->query($cusProcedure); // <-- Executing SQL

if(! $returnCusProcedure )
{
    die('Could not create procedure: ' . $conn->error);
}
else
{
    echo "Procedure created successfully<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not actually creating the Procedure, only defining it as a string, thanks to @outlyer for bringing that to my attention. I have since edited the code like so and everything is working now:

```
$returnCusProcedure = "
    DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllCustomers()
    BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS;
    END //
    DELIMITER ; ";

$executeQuery = mysqli_query($conn, $returnCusProcedure );

if($conn->query($executeQuery) == TRUE)
{
    die('Could not create procedure: ' . $conn->error);
}
else
{
    echo "Procedure created successfully<br/>";
}
```